# How to change default component and module name (app.module.ts and app.component.ts) while doing ng g application app in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have an angular workspace. There I want to create one application with different module and component name, rather than app.module.ts or app.component.ts. Want to do that using angular cli.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do so with the Angular CLI.
You would need to extend it by creating a custom schematic : https://angular.io/guide/schematics-authoring